# Trouble Importing whatsapp-web.js in a WordPress Plugin Development

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I create plugin I name it sendblast.

Like other plugin, I make index.php, functions.php, sendblast.php with src and css folder with sub folder i name it modules.

I install node js, npm init, and npm install @wordpress/scripts. I also install whatsapp-web.js, npm i whatsapp-web.js.

Actually, I'm already make working code, but not in plugin.

[image]

```
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js");

const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    // proxyAuthentication: { username: 'username', password: 'password' },
    puppeteer: { 
        // args: ['--proxy-server=proxy-server-that-requires-authentication.example.com'],
        headless: true
    }
});

client.initialize();

client.on('loading_screen', (percent, message) => {
    console.log('LOADING SCREEN', percent, message);
});

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('authenticated', () => {
    console.log('AUTHENTICATED');
});

client.on('auth_failure', msg => {
    // Fired if session restore was unsuccessful
    console.error('AUTHENTICATION FAILURE', msg);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('READY');

    // Array of numbers where you want to send the message.
    const numbers = ["+628xxxxxxxx"];

    // Loop through the numbers and send the message to each number.
    numbers.forEach(number => {
        // Getting chatId from the number.
        // We have to delete "+" from the beginning and add "@c.us" at the end of the number.
        const chatId = number.substring(1) + "@c.us";

        // Your message.
        const text = `Yey, its working!`;
        // Sending message.
        client.sendMessage(chatId, text);
    });
});
```

but when I require from my src folder, I get so many Errors in terminal.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js"); // I can't call it inside plugin.
class appJS{
    constructor(){
        this.events();
    }
    events(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
        });
    }



}

export default appJS;
```

Please take a look at my screenshot, below:

[image]

Anyone understand how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: That's not code that's supposed to run in the browser, or a plugin. It's a node app that's supposed to run on a web server. You can't put this in a plugin.

Comment: But I want to use it inside plugin, is it possible? any solution?

Comment: Should I use add_rewrite_rule()?

Comment: You simply can't use it inside a plugin. It's impossible. It requires a Node.js server to run, and you can't provide that with a plugin.

Comment: Do you have any info about alternative of whatsapp-web.js? That I can use for plugin development?

Comment: My teacher said, impossible is nothing.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. You cannot ship a node server with a WordPress plugin. You can ship it separately and require your users to set up a node server, but you cannot run this JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: if so, can you give me alternative solutions for sending whatsapp message to many contact?

Comment: I'm able to send qrcode to browser, but still cannot run it into wordpress add_rewrite_rules(), can you please take a look at my plugin @JacobPeattie? Thanks https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14-snRKXBFN0I3C8NxnhOQtE0UUOV2THc?usp=sharing